# jQuery select only tr in main table, not in nested tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to capture click on table rows But I want to capture only master/main table rows.If Rows have again tables I want to ignore them.
I am looking for selector which works with .on() and only selects master table rows not nested table rows.

**Requirements:**

1. Table has dynamic rows so I am looking for solution with `.on()`
2. Solution selector must be generic, I dont want to use tr.odd or tr.even classes restriction

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/8vpg6dp6/9/

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //'tbody > tr:first:parent tr
  $('#example').on('click', 'tbody > tr', function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    //do something with row in master table
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="display dataTable no-footer" id="example" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">Name</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 124px;" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending">Position</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 62px;" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending">Office</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 37px;" aria-label="Extn.: activate to sort column ascending">Extn.</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 63px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Start date</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 56px;" aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>5797</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td colspan="6">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Jill</td>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a starting `>` to your selector:

```
$('#example').on('click', '> tbody > tr:not(:has(>td>table))', function(e) {
    // ...
}
```

This way only direct `tbody` children of your table will be selected. Also with `:not(:has(>td>table))` you filter out rows which contain nested tables.

Here is an forked [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5bbrx5f/1/).

Comment: It isn't really, but of course the event bubbles up to the outer row. So you even don't want this to happen?

Comment: @django you need to stop this bubbling up of event.

Comment: yes, I only want to accept click on mater table row, for  example select it but nested table rows must bot be selected.

Comment: Updated my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell Thankx. This is what i wanted. But I also found a solution.Please check my update above but I find it better

Comment: Well, if your answer is the one that meets your case best, you should add it as an answer. Please never answer your question inside the question.

Comment: too obscure and difficult to follow but in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by stopping the event propagation. Assign the id or class to inner table and stop the event propagation there.

```
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td colspan="6">
    <table style="width:100%" id="innerTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        .....
```

So write another selector just after your current code and stop the propagation like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//'tbody > tr:first:parent tr
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody > tr', function(e) {
console.log(this);
//do something with row in master table
});

$('#innerTable').on('click','tbody > tr', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //'tbody > tr:first:parent tr
  $('#example').on('click', '#example > tbody > tr', function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    //do something with row in master table
  });
});
```

just added your table id

Comment: this is not working at all actually, you can review it

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Give class names for tr which has inner table. For example:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd has_inner_table">
  <td colspan="6">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the above code, I gave "has_inner_table" name to the row that has inner table.

And give name for other rows which dont have inner table.

for example.

```
<tr role="row" class="even not_have_inner_table">
  <td class="sorting_1">Angelica Ramos</td>
  <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
  <td>London</td>
  <td>5797</td>
  <td>2009/10/09</td>
  <td>$1,200,000</td>
</tr>
```

Above , I gave "not_have_inner_table" .

And in your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //'tbody > tr:first:parent tr
  $('#example').on('click', 'tbody > tr.not_have_inner_table', function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    //do something with row in master table
  });
 });
```

Which means only `tr.not_have_inner_table` will be affected. I am not very sure about syntax but most probably like this. Select rows with specific class name.

Answer (score 0):

My current Solution but @Linus Caldwell has better suggestion with selector only

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //'tbody > tr:first:parent tr
  $('#example').on('click', 'tbody > tr', function(e) {
    var _parentTable = $(e.target).closest('table');
    if (_parentTable.is($('#example'))) {
      //do something with row in master table
      console.log(this);
    }
  });
});
```